# Handling onActivityResult in Android app having more than one activity

Tags: android

In my android app, I have a main activity which creates two other sub activites through intent. Now, both the sub activity return result to the main activity. In my main activity,
how do I handle two "onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)" since it cant have two methods with same name in a given class. Hope my question is clear..

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You change the `requestCode` that you use when you call `startActivityForResult`.

EDIT: for example, I use this:

```
startActivityForResult(i, App.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
```

and this:

```
startActivityForResult(i, App.MANUAL_INPUT);
```

and then you filter the results like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            switch(requestCode){
            case App.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                if(resultCode != RESULT_OK){
                    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.label_bluetooth_disabled), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            case App.MANUAL_INPUT:
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: This is a really bad design. In fact, the `Toast` is unreachable code, since you enter the switch only if `resultCode` is equal `RESULT_OK`. You should always use an outer (and single) `switch` for the `requestCode`, and inside every `case` check for the different `resultCodes`. Any other design for saving a couple of lines of code will eventually be a source of bugs.

Answer (score 10):

That's what the `requestCode` is for.  So you'd have a setup like this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode)
        case ACTIVITY1:
           if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activity 1 returned OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           break;
        case ACTIVITY2:
           if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activity 2 returned OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           break;
}
```

Where ACTIVITY1 and ACTIVITY2 are constants in your `Activity`.  You'd call them like so:

`startActivityForResult(activity1Intent, ACTIVITY1);`

and

`startActivityForResult(activity2Intent, ACTIVITY2);`

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to return any kind of data from a subactivity in the result intent parameter:

Sub-activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent ();
intent.putExtra ("string_1", "hello");
intent.putExtra ("string_2", "world");
intent.putExtra ("int_1", 1000);
intent.putExtra ("long_1", 2000l);
activity.setResult (Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```

_

Parent activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        String string_1 = intent.getStringExtra ("string_1", "");
        String string_2 = intent.getStringExtra ("string_2", "");
        int int_1 = intent.getIntExtra ("int_1", 0);
        long long_1 = intent.getLongExtra ("long_1", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: activity.setResult (Activity.RESULT_OK, intent); what is activity here parentActivity or object?

Comment: @SureshMaidaragi I don't think it's the parentActivity, because you don't have access to that in the child activity. So it must be the child activity itself. If you are in a subclass of Activity, you can probably replace **activity** with **this** .  ( "this" is probably what you mean by object )

Answer (score 1):

You can use swicth the requestcode for different result

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
 {

      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       switch (requestCode) {

          case (1): 
          {
            // do this if request code is 1.
          }
          break;

          case (2):
          {
            // do this if request code is 2.
          }
          break;
  }
```