# How can I get a result from an onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)?

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm working on an Android project which allow the user to take a picture using the camera.

My method looks like this :

```
private void takePicture(){
        Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(camera, 1337);
    }
```

And in my onActivityResult I take the picture and store it in my SdCard. I trying to modify my takePicture() function to return the path of the picture (String instead void).

I already know that getPath() from java.io.File allow me to do that.

> So my question is : how can I modify my function to return the path of
>   the picture?

Comment: Take a look to this post: [handling-onactivityresult](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262405/handling-onactivityresult-in-android-app-having-more-than-one-activity)

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent), take a look there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`takePicture` won't be able to return a path, as it'll return before your intent has completed. You'll need to do something with the path inside `onActivityResult`

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the code to get the path of captured and stored image in pictureCallback**

in this code ***`mFilePath`*** is the string which is holding the path of image...

```
PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();

                String mFilePath = pictureFile.getAbsolutePath(); 
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: He already says that he's storing the image to SD card in `onActivityResult`, so why is this relevant?

Comment: @Rawkode in the above examples there are methods which shows the path he just need to make void method to String type and return the path...

Comment: @Rawkode whether this answer is useful..??

Comment: The question is "How can I modify `takePicture` to return a `String`" that `String` being the path of the image. Which still isn't possible.

Comment: @Rawkode brother you had already mentioned that `takePicture` can not be return the String value so i just showing him another way to getPath,.. if i write in my question the same you write in my words is duplication so i didn't write that and just show him way how to do..