# How to start intent activity with instance of the class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My class activity should return callback interface to other class
step1. class 1 open Activity
step2. Activity return callback to class1

Can i do somthing like that?

```
AccountPickerActivity pickerActivity = new AccountPickerActivity(new AccountPickerActivity.onPickAccountFromPickerIntent() {
    @Override
    public void onPickAccountFromPickerIntent() {
                onConnected(null);

    }
});
Intent i = new Intent(mContext, pickerActivity.getClass());
mContext.startActivity(i);
```

Or there is any way to call interface from activity to other class (witout using static)?

Comment: Not possible the way you are doing it. Read this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: And this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262405/handling-onactivityresult-in-android-app-having-more-than-one-activity

Comment: I know that but the class that open the activity is not activity, you think i need to get the activity result from the root Activity?

Comment: you may need to restructure the logic you are working on to avoid this situation, because proper way is to open activity for result,and read results with onactivityresult...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `startActivityForResult()` for starting Activity2 from Activity1. You can setResults from Activity2 and when it gets back to Activity1 the overriden method `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {//}` can receive the results.

Read in detail : [Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)